# Configure VPS to access SSH with subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, vps, subdomain, nameserver

Well, I just bought a unmanaged VPS with DirectSpace to try the service out.
I'm currently able to access it through the two IP adresses that they gave me, but now I'd like to get access to it through my Domain, which I get with GoDaddy through GoogleApps.

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
ssh username@server1.mydomain.com
```

and get access to the shell this way.
Also, since I'm using the GoDaddy Name Servers and they are working good enough, I wouldn't like reassign them to my own host (ns1.mydomain.com, ns2.mydomain.com).

I've read somewhere that it is posible by setting an A Record, but honestly I'm lost.
Finally, I'd like to be able to use the VPS for hosting my own Web Site and also some other Customer Sites (with its own domains), so please, let me know if somebody can give me a clue on this.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the dashboard provided by GoDaddy (I haven't used GoDaddy DNS service so wouldn't be able to walk you through). There will be an option to add an `A` record. Over there add an `A` record for your domain.

```
IP_ADDRESS A server1
```

For hosting content of your site and other customers you would need to use virtual hosting in Apache. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/

Once the virtual hosting is configured you can ask your customers to change their `A` record to your IP.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm still having a couple of doubts, can I assign 2 diferent IP's for the same A Record? ie. "127.0.1.1 A server1" and "127.0.5.3 A server1". And also, I already have a lot of "@" put there by google, won't this interfere some way with my new A Record? should I drop them off?

Comment: I've just tried this out, thats just what I wanted! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to associate GLUE records with the godaddy DNS setup and point ns1.yourdomain.com to your server.
You'll obviously need to setup BINDDNS or something to that affect on your VPS.
I have just completed a setup exactly the same on my VPS - Email me dave[at]proliveonline.com and I can maybe shadow your session and walk you through it?
Also have setup apache vhosts for several sites on VPS and email forwding for entire domains or for individual emails.. Abd web forwding. Basically tried to replicate a 'ZonEdit' service (in regards to DNS)

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want, to host my own DNS, because I only have one small VPS, so if something go wrong, I'll lose every Name Server info.